# Google maps not displaying plus/minus signs on zoom control

Tags: google-maps, meteor

I've got a Meteor web app using google maps getting the map info from the customer address.

```
getCoordinates(mapsArray(), function (coords) {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0] + 0.00145, coords[1] + 0.00135), // For some reason it centers off of the address entered. These numbers compensate.
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scaleControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    styles: [...styles here...]
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: coords_objLat.f + 0.00145, lng: coords_objLon.b + 0.00135 },
    title: mapAddress[0]
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
});

function getCoordinates(address, callback) {
  var coordinates;
  geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function (results) {
    coords_objLat = results[0].geometry.viewport.f;
    coords_objLon = results[0].geometry.viewport.b;
    coordinates = [coords_objLat.f, coords_objLon.b];
    callback(coordinates);
  })
}
```

The map sits inside a Materialize Card, although I'm not sure how relevant that is.

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light" id="map">
               <!--<map is here>-->
           </div>
.
.
.
```

CSS:

```
#map {
height: 200px;
background-color: #01579b;
padding: 0;
}
```

What it looks like. There should be a plus and minus sign and a human figure on the lower right controls. Don't remember seeing this before:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah. Problem solved. It was the 'waves-effect' class in the map div that was the culprit. It was affecting the image somehow.

Answer (score 1):

From [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls):

> By default, all the controls disappear if the map is too small
>   (200x200px). You can override this behavior by explicitly setting the
>   control to be visible. See Adding Controls to the Map.

Try changing the size of the map to 201 px to see if that makes a difference. Otherwise, you can override the behaviour. Instructions here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.